# Rust LAPACK vs Numpy inconsistency for QR factorization

Tags: numpy, rust, scipy, linear-algebra, lapack

I have a Rust snippet that uses LAPACK to compute QR factorization, but I'm getting different answers between my code and Numpy. But when I look at the documentation and compare the two implementations, it's not clear what I'm doing wrong.

Numpy code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(1,25).reshape((6,4))
np.linalg.qr(A, mode="raw")[0]
```

Rust code:

```
        let m = 6 as i32;
        let n = 4 as i32;
        let mut data = vec![1.0, 5.0,  9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0,
                            2.0, 6.0, 10.0, 14.0, 18.0, 22.0,
                            3.0, 7.0, 11.0, 15.0, 19.0, 23.0,
                            4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 16.0, 20.0, 24.0];
        let buf = data.as_mut_slice();

        let tau_size = min(m, n) as usize;
        let mut tau = vec![0.0; tau_size];

        let lwork: i32 = -1;
        let mut info: i32 = 0;
        let mut work = vec![0.0; 1];

        // Get the worksize
        unsafe {
            dgeqrf(m, n, buf, m, tau.as_mut_slice(), work.as_mut_slice(), lwork, &mut info);
        }
        if info != 0 {
            return Err(Error::Arrow("failed to get work size for matrix".to_string()));
        }

        let lwork = work[0] as i32;
        let mut work = vec![0.0; lwork as usize];

        // Compute QR
        unsafe {
            dgeqrf(m, n, buf, m, tau.as_mut_slice(), work.as_mut_slice(), lwork, &mut info);
        }
        if info != 0 {
            return Err(Error::Arrow("failed to compute QR (dgeqrf) for matrix".to_string()));
        }

        println!("Raw {:?}", data);
```

The output matrix differs in the bottom-right [2x4] rectangle

Numpy output:

```
array([[-31.7, 0.153, 0.275, 0.397, 0.52, 0.642],
       [-33.8, -1.29, 0.0837, -0.123, -0.33, -0.537],
       [-35.9, -2.58, 1.29e-15, -0.2, 0.263, 0.397],
       [-38, -3.88, 2.87e-15, 5.22e-16, -0.106, 0.705]])
```

Rust output:

```
array([[-31.7, 0.153, 0.275, 0.397, 0.52, 0.642],
       [-33.8, -1.29, 0.0837, -0.123, -0.33, -0.537],
       [-35.9, -2.58, 1.14e-15, -0.631, -0.172, 0.484],
       [-38, -3.88, 2.22e-15, 1.55e-16, 0.541, 0.327]])
```

Feels like I'm just missing something obvious. Thanks for any pointers!

I looked through the numpy code, LAPACK docs on netlib, etc.

Comment: I would gently guess that both outputs are correct, in that they are indeed the Householder reflections representation of the `Q` basis and both would work. `Q` will only have four columns, representing the 4-dimensional subspace in R^6 reachable by the columns of `A`, so I would guess that the algorithm has some flexibility in deciding those lower-right coefficients. But given that Numpy is calling [`geqrf`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/99eaf340ca9b6d06d65c4ef9a5e96a1a83c42909/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.cpp#LL3262C27-L3262C32), I am surprised it's differing from `dgeqrf` output 

Comment: My question is, do you need the Rust and Numpy outputs to match exactly (e.g., porting a library)? Or do you just need the Rust version to be mathematically correct and you're worried it's not because it's disagreeing with Numpy? If the latter, it should be straightforward to confirm that the output of your wrapper to `dgeqrf` is correct by converting `h` and `tau` to `Q` and `R` and confirming the identity `Q @ R = A` (in Rust).

Comment: Thanks @AhmedFasih Ideally they would match which makes unit testing easy. But certainly as long as it's mathematically correct it sholud be fine. Unfortunately, the Rust produced Q is not orthogonal. i.e., q.T.dot(q) is not the identity matrix.